# Compulsion of GCS usage while using bigQuery with spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, spotify

I am working on local machine not on the Google cloud environment to work with BigQuery using ***spark***, I gone through the documentations provided by google for BigQuery, i did not find enough documentation about how to use BigQuery and spark together, whatever i found [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/connectors/bigquery) is as:

> When using the connector, you will also be charged for any associated
>   BigQuery usage fees. Additionally, the BigQuery connector for Hadoop
>   downloads data into a Google Cloud Storage bucket before running a
>   Hadoop job. After the Hadoop job successfully completes, the data is
>   deleted from Cloud Storage. You are charged for storage according to
>   Cloud Storage pricing. To avoid excess charges, check your Cloud
>   Storage account and make sure to remove unneeded temporary files.

My question is why it is compulsory to unnecessary use of two cloud services BigQuery and cloud storage, even if i wanted to use BigQuery only?
also, cloud anybody suggest any reference/blog where i can find clear information to execute the *Standard SQL* queries using ***spark API*** same as the way we execute in web UI of BigQuery.

@spotify: I am using the module you have implement to work with BigQuery and spark available [here](https://github.com/spotify/spark-bigquery) but as you mentioned there this module works with legacy sql only, so any recommendations to change code to make that module works with Standard SQL, as it was working with legacy sql.

Comment: Because, as the docs state: _"the BigQuery connector for Hadoop downloads data into a Google Cloud Storage bucket before running a Hadoop job"_. So, you need to pay for those storage costs. _"execute the Standard SQL queries using spark API same as the way we execute in web UI of BigQuery."_ I don't quite get you here. Are you simply looking for BigQuery's API reference?

Comment: thats what i am asking why "the BigQuery connector for Hadoop downloads data into a Google Cloud Storage bucket before running a Hadoop job"? 
I need API for Spark that allow me to provide query in string format like java.sql.Statement.execute() method in java to execute the SQL Queries.

Comment: Because that's how it works! It's the same even for Cloud Dataflow. BigQuery's table(s) are exported to GCS first, and then read. My first guess as to why would be because it most likely greatly simplifies reading the data in parallel by the workers (Hadoop, Dataflow/Beam etc.). As to your 2nd part - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/ & https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/partners/simba-drivers/